# Magento Multiple store views - Language switch issue

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I have setup a multi lingual site using magento version 1.3.2.4 and have come accross some weird problems. Hoping that I could get some assistance.

The requirement was to add the new store view (dutch) and also maintain the current stores url structure, so I couldnt use 'Add store codes to urls' in the admin configuration as it would append the current urls with the default store code (fr). So, ultimately I needed the following url structures:

Default language (fr) url style : http://www.domainname.com
Dutch version url style : http://www.domainname.com/nl

For this I performed the the following steps:

1. I created a store view (code nl)
2. I created a folder by the name of nl

   - I copied the .htaccess and index.php from the main web root and pasted it in this folder
   - I modified the code as follows in index.php :

   Mage::app()->getLocale()->setLocale('nl_NL');

   $mageRunCode = 'Netherlands';

   $mageRunType = 'store';

   Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(1); // 1 being the nl store id

   Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);

When I launch the site, and goto http://www.domainname.com/nl the interface is in dutch as expected, but when I perform the following tasks I get redirected

back to the default language:

1. Login
2. Goto checkout/cart
3. Goto new user signup

Upon checking the view-source of the DOM I notice that some urls are pointing to the default language and not the nl language. For example the login form's action attribute is http://www.domain.com/customer/account/loginPost/ and not http://www.domain.com/nl/customer/account/loginPost/

Warm regards,

Answer (score 2):

Hi instead of creating such a stuff .You can use this [extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/googletranslate.html) . Hope this help you and you can easily switch your language without creating a store view.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I have to create a store view as the prices of the product differ

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, cant have the same store code twice and when i try a new code it want link to the translation pack!